# Why doesn't ASCII character 144 display in Win 7?

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, windows-xp, ascii, chr

I need to indicate a demarcation within a string being displayed in a grid cell.

My code currently uses `Chr(144)` which is a small rectangle.

This works in `XP`, however the symbol doesn't display in `Win 7`.  It just doesn't display anything so `Debug.Print "#" & Chr(144) & "#"` will just display `##`

Why doesn't the character display in `Win 7`?

Comment: It's not an ASCII character, they only go from 0-127, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII.

Comment: A square usually means the displayed font does not contain an image for the value. Chr 144 in extended ascii is not a box http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-e-acute-accent-e-acute-uppercase-ascii-code-144.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no ASCII character 144. ASCII only runs up to 127.
So did you mean Windows-1252 character 144? That happens to be a non-assigned character. (See [character map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_1252)).

So the system prints the symbol for a non-existent character, which happens to be a rectangle in the font used on your XP machine, and nothing in the font on your Win 7 machine.

To display a proper rectangle, take a look at the geometric shapes in the Unicode region [U+25A0..U+25FF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf). U+25AF looks like it's the one you want.

**Edit**
I see you're using VB.Net now, so forget about ASCII and Windows-1252. VB.NET uses UTF-16 internally, so you don't have to be afraid that you can't display a certain Unicode codepoint. Just write `chr(&H25AF)`

Comment: What would be a rectangle in VB6?

Comment: I never worked with VB6, so I have no idea how to display those higher Unicode characters there. Would `ChrW` work?